# Outlook rule across mail boxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

At my workplace, I am supposed to use two different email address (one with the employer and another one with the customer). I have setup outlook with both these mailboxes and is using this method for couple of years. With this setup though, I am always having a problem when people send me email on both the email address, I end up getting same email twice which causes me keep on cleaning up one or the other mailbox. I have several rules setup but I am not able to figure out what would be the best way to setup a rule across two mailboxes, so that when the same email is received at one place, it should delete one of those.

(One thing I could do off course is request one of the mailbox administrator to forward all emails to other account so that I end of maintaining just one. But I am not sure how effective that would be and due to work expected besides me, I would choose that as a last resort if nothing else works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you have two mailboxes: user1@a.com and user2@b.com. And you want user1@a.com to be the primary one. Create this rule for user2@b.com:

*Apply rule on messages I receive -> where my name is in the To or Cc box **and** sent to people or public group (type user1@b.com) -> delete it **and** stop processing more rules.*

Now all messages that come to user2@b.com mailbox and additionally addressed to user1@a.com will be deleted in user2@b.com mailbox.

Comment: That was a good idea. I did make one change though, instead of deleting the message completely, I moved those to a separate folder such that I can take a look for any important message may be mis-classified and then delete. This works fine!